# what's the possible cause of iOS unit test not responding?

Tags: ios, unit-testing

When I run the unit test today, `xcode` says testing... but no test case is executed. After a long while, it's over.

I have no clue why it's like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.Clean Project Derived Data

2.Product > Clean

3.Run the app

4.Wait for Xcode indexing to finish

Comment: You should to create a new proyect to see if it works.

Comment: Should be caused by code, earlier branch runs well.